# Directx 11: emulating palette swapping with shader 5.0 and c++

Tags: c++, shaders, directx11, palette

i'm trying to swapping the colors using a texture as index and a second one as palette.

Here is the full listing of the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <vector>
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <d3dcommon.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <xnamath.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx10.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "D3dcompiler.lib")





// define the screen resolution
#define     SCREEN_WIDTH    300
#define     SCREEN_HEIGHT   180
const float SCREEN_DEPTH    = 1000.0f;
const float SCREEN_NEAR     = 0.1f;

struct SIMPLEVERTEX
{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    XMFLOAT2 Tex;
    XMFLOAT4 Color;
};

struct CONSTANTBUFFER
{
    XMMATRIX Scaling;
    XMMATRIX World;
    XMMATRIX View;
    XMMATRIX Projection;
};






// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK    WindowProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );
// Gestione delle DirectX 11
bool                InitializeDirectX11( HWND p_Hwnd );
void                CleanupDirectX11();
void                BeginScene(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha);
void                EndScene();
void                Render();

// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
    WNDCLASSEX          wc = {};

    wc.cbSize           = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );
    wc.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc      = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance        = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor          = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    //wc.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
    wc.lpszClassName    = L"WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx( &wc );

    unsigned int        width, height;

    width               = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    height              = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    RECT                rect;

    rect.left           = 0;
    rect.top            = 0;
    rect.right          = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    rect.bottom         = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    AdjustWindowRect( &rect, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE );
    rect.right          -= rect.left;
    rect.bottom         -= rect.top;
    rect.left           = (width - rect.right) / 2;
    rect.top            = (height - rect.bottom) / 2;

    // Creazione della window.
    HWND    hWnd;

    hWnd                = CreateWindowEx( NULL, L"WindowClass", L"Palette swapping", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );

    // Inizializza DirectX 11.
    InitializeDirectX11(hWnd);

    ShowWindow( hWnd, nCmdShow );

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG     msg;

    while( TRUE )
    {
        while( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }

        if( msg.message == WM_QUIT )
            break;
        else
        {
            // Render
            Render();
        }
    }

    CleanupDirectX11();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( message )
    {
    case WM_KEYUP:
        {
            if( wParam == VK_ESCAPE )
            {
                DestroyWindow( hWnd );
                return 0;
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            return 0;
        }
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT     ps;
            BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );
            EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
        }
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc ( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
}




IDXGIFactory                * g_Factory             = NULL;
IDXGIAdapter                * g_Adapter             = NULL;
ID3D11Device                * g_Device              = NULL;
ID3D11DeviceContext         * g_Context             = NULL;
IDXGISwapChain              * g_Swapchain           = NULL;
ID3D11RenderTargetView      * g_Targetview          = NULL;
ID3D11VertexShader          * g_VertexShader        = NULL;
ID3D11InputLayout           * g_VertexLayout        = NULL;
ID3D11PixelShader           * g_PixelShader         = NULL;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView    * g_TextureRV           = NULL;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView    * g_PaletteRV           = NULL;
ID3D11SamplerState          * g_Sampler             = NULL;
ID3D11BlendState            * g_BlendState          = NULL;
ID3D11Buffer                * g_VertexBuffer        = NULL;
ID3D11Buffer                * g_ConstantBuffer      = NULL;
XMMATRIX                    g_World;
XMMATRIX                    g_View;
XMMATRIX                    g_Projection;
XMMATRIX                    g_Scaling;
XMMATRIX                    g_2nd;

ID3D11Texture2D             * g_pDepthStencil       = NULL;
ID3D11DepthStencilView      * g_pDepthStencilView   = NULL;


bool InitializeDirectX11( HWND p_Hwnd )
{

    // Create DXGI factory.
    if( FAILED( CreateDXGIFactory( __uuidof( IDXGIFactory ), (void**)&g_Factory ) ) )
        return false;

    // Main adapter.
    g_Factory->EnumAdapters( 0, &g_Adapter );

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL       Featurerequested        = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
    UINT                    Featurelevel            = 1;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL       Featuresupported;

    // Watch out, you must pass D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN to avoid E_INVALIDARG result.
    if( FAILED( D3D11CreateDevice( g_Adapter, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN, NULL, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, &Featurerequested, Featurelevel, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &g_Device, &Featuresupported, &g_Context ) ) )
        return false;

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC    Chaindesc;

    Chaindesc.BufferCount                           = 1;
    Chaindesc.BufferDesc.Width                      = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    Chaindesc.BufferDesc.Height                     = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    Chaindesc.BufferDesc.Format                     = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    Chaindesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator      = 0;
    Chaindesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator    = 1;
    Chaindesc.BufferDesc.Scaling                    = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
    Chaindesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering           = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    Chaindesc.BufferUsage                           = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    Chaindesc.OutputWindow                          = p_Hwnd;
    Chaindesc.SampleDesc.Count                      = 1;
    Chaindesc.SampleDesc.Quality                    = 0;
    Chaindesc.Windowed                              = true;
    Chaindesc.SwapEffect                            = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    Chaindesc.Flags                                 = 0;

    if( FAILED( g_Factory->CreateSwapChain( g_Device, &Chaindesc, &g_Swapchain ) ) )
        return false;

    // Get the pointer to the back buffer.
    ID3D11Texture2D *       Backbuffer;

    if( FAILED( g_Swapchain->GetBuffer( 0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&Backbuffer ) ) )
        return false;

    // Create the render target view with the back buffer pointer.
    if( FAILED( g_Device->CreateRenderTargetView( Backbuffer, NULL, &g_Targetview ) ) )
        return false;

    // Release pointer to the back buffer as we no longer need it.
    Backbuffer->Release();

    // Create depth stencil texture
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth;
    ZeroMemory( &descDepth, sizeof(descDepth) );
    descDepth.Width                         = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    descDepth.Height                        = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    descDepth.MipLevels                     = 1;
    descDepth.ArraySize                     = 1;
    descDepth.Format                        = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Count              = 1;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality            = 0;
    descDepth.Usage                         = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    descDepth.BindFlags                     = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    descDepth.CPUAccessFlags                = 0;
    descDepth.MiscFlags                     = 0;
    HRESULT hr = g_Device->CreateTexture2D( &descDepth, NULL, &g_pDepthStencil );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return false;

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC dsDesc;

    // Depth test parameters
    dsDesc.DepthEnable                      = true;
    dsDesc.DepthWriteMask                   = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
    dsDesc.DepthFunc                        = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS_EQUAL;

    // Stencil test parameters
    dsDesc.StencilEnable                    = true;
    dsDesc.StencilReadMask                  = 0xFF;
    dsDesc.StencilWriteMask                 = 0xFF;

    // Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing
    dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp          = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp     = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
    dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp          = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc            = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    // Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing
    dsDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp           = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp      = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
    dsDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp           = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc             = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    // Create depth stencil state
    ID3D11DepthStencilState * pDSState;
    g_Device->CreateDepthStencilState(&dsDesc, &pDSState);

    // Bind depth stencil state
    g_Context->OMSetDepthStencilState(pDSState, 1);

    // Create the depth stencil view
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC descDSV;
    ZeroMemory( &descDSV, sizeof(descDSV) );
    descDSV.Format                          = descDepth.Format;
    descDSV.ViewDimension                   = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    descDSV.Texture2D.MipSlice              = 0;
    hr = g_Device->CreateDepthStencilView( g_pDepthStencil, &descDSV, &g_pDepthStencilView );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return false;

    g_Context->OMSetRenderTargets( 1, &g_Targetview, g_pDepthStencilView );

    // Setup the Viewport for rendering.
    D3D11_VIEWPORT      Viewport;

    Viewport.Width      = (float)SCREEN_WIDTH;
    Viewport.Height     = (float)SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    Viewport.MinDepth   = 0.0f;
    Viewport.MaxDepth   = 1.0f;
    Viewport.TopLeftX   = 0.0f;
    Viewport.TopLeftY   = 0.0f;

    // Create the Viewport.
    g_Context->RSSetViewports( 1, &Viewport );

    // Compile the vertex shader
    ID3DBlob            * Errorblob = NULL;
    ID3DBlob            * VSBlob = NULL;
    if( FAILED( D3DX11CompileFromFile( L"Palette.fx", NULL, NULL, "VS", "vs_5_0", D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS, 0, NULL, &VSBlob, &Errorblob, NULL ) ) )
        return false;

    // Create the vertex shader
    if( FAILED( g_Device->CreateVertexShader( VSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), VSBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &g_VertexShader ) ) )
    {   
        VSBlob->Release();
        return false;
    }

    // Define the input Layout
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC Layout[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
    };

    UINT                Elements = ARRAYSIZE( Layout );

    // Create the input Layout
    g_Device->CreateInputLayout( Layout, Elements, VSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), VSBlob->GetBufferSize(), &g_VertexLayout );
    VSBlob->Release();
    if( !g_VertexLayout )
        return false;

    // Set the input layout
    g_Context->IASetInputLayout( g_VertexLayout );

    // Compile the pixel shader
    ID3DBlob            * PSBlob = NULL;
    if( FAILED( D3DX11CompileFromFile( L"Palette.fx", NULL, NULL, "PS", "ps_5_0", D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS, 0, NULL, &PSBlob, &Errorblob, NULL ) ) )
    {
        LPSTR text = (char *)Errorblob->GetBufferPointer();
        return false;
    }

    // Create the pixel shader
    g_Device->CreatePixelShader( PSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), PSBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &g_PixelShader );
    PSBlob->Release();
    if( !g_PixelShader )
        return false;

    // Create vertex buffer
    SIMPLEVERTEX Vertices[] =
    {
        { XMFLOAT3( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f ), XMFLOAT2( 0.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { XMFLOAT3( -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f ), XMFLOAT2( 0.0f, 0.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { XMFLOAT3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f ), XMFLOAT2( 1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { XMFLOAT3( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f ), XMFLOAT2( 1.0f, 0.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) }
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC           Buffer = {};

    Buffer.Usage                = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    Buffer.ByteWidth            = sizeof( SIMPLEVERTEX ) * ARRAYSIZE( Vertices );
    Buffer.BindFlags            = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    Buffer.CPUAccessFlags       = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA      Initdata = {};

    Initdata.pSysMem            = Vertices;
    if( FAILED( g_Device->CreateBuffer( &Buffer, &Initdata, &g_VertexBuffer ) ) )
        return false;

    // Set vertex buffer
    UINT                        Stride = sizeof( SIMPLEVERTEX );
    UINT                        Offset = 0;
    g_Context->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &g_VertexBuffer, &Stride, &Offset );

    // Set primitive topology
    g_Context->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP);

    // Create the constant buffer
    Buffer.Usage                = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    Buffer.ByteWidth            = sizeof(CONSTANTBUFFER);
    Buffer.BindFlags            = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    Buffer.CPUAccessFlags       = 0;
    if( FAILED( g_Device->CreateBuffer( &Buffer, NULL, &g_ConstantBuffer ) ) )
        return false;

    // Create index texture.
    if( FAILED( D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile( g_Device, L"Vortex.png", NULL, NULL, &g_TextureRV, NULL ) ) )
        return false;

    // Create palette texture.
    if( FAILED( D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile( g_Device, L"Palette8x1.png", NULL, NULL, &g_PaletteRV, NULL ) ) )
        return false;

    // Create the sample state
    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC          Sampler;

    ZeroMemory( &Sampler, sizeof(Sampler) );
    Sampler.Filter              = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT;
    Sampler.AddressU            = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_BORDER;
    Sampler.AddressV            = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_BORDER;
    Sampler.AddressW            = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_BORDER;
    Sampler.ComparisonFunc      = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
    Sampler.MinLOD              = 0;
    Sampler.MaxLOD              = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;

    if( FAILED( g_Device->CreateSamplerState( &Sampler, &g_Sampler ) ) )
        return false;

    // Create the blend state
    D3D11_BLEND_DESC            BlendState;

    ZeroMemory( &BlendState, sizeof(D3D11_BLEND_DESC) );
    BlendState.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable              = true;
    BlendState.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend                 = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
    BlendState.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend                = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
    BlendState.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp                  = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    BlendState.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha            = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
    BlendState.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha           = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
    BlendState.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha             = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    BlendState.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask    = 0x0f;


    g_Device->CreateBlendState( &BlendState, &g_BlendState );

    float blendFactor[4]        = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    UINT sampleMask             = 0xffffffff;

    g_Context->OMSetBlendState( g_BlendState, blendFactor, sampleMask );


    // Initialize the world matrix
    g_World                     = XMMatrixIdentity();
    g_World                     = XMMatrixTranslation( 0, 0, 22 );
    g_2nd                       = XMMatrixIdentity();
    g_2nd                       = XMMatrixTranslation( 42, -36, 20 );

    // Initialize the view matrix
    XMVECTOR        Eye         = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f );
    XMVECTOR        At          = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    XMVECTOR        Up          = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    g_View                      = XMMatrixLookAtLH( Eye, At, Up );

    // Initialize the projection matrix
    g_Projection                = XMMatrixOrthographicLH((FLOAT) SCREEN_WIDTH, (FLOAT) SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.0f, 10000.0f);

    // Scaling.
    g_Scaling                   = XMMatrixIdentity();
    g_Scaling._11 = 64.0;
    g_Scaling._22 = 64.0;

    return true;
}



void CleanupDirectX11()
{
    // Rilascio.
    if( g_ConstantBuffer ) g_ConstantBuffer->Release();

    if( g_VertexBuffer ) g_VertexBuffer->Release();

    if( g_PixelShader ) g_PixelShader->Release();

    if( g_VertexLayout ) g_VertexLayout->Release();

    if( g_VertexShader ) g_VertexShader->Release();

    if( g_Targetview ) g_Targetview->Release();

    if( g_Swapchain ) g_Swapchain->Release();

    if( g_Device) g_Device->Release();

    if( g_Adapter) g_Adapter->Release();

    if( g_Factory ) g_Factory->Release();
}




void BeginScene(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha)
{
    float color[4];


    // Setup the color to clear the buffer to.
    color[0] = red;
    color[1] = green;
    color[2] = blue;
    color[3] = alpha;

    // Clear the back buffer.
    g_Context->ClearRenderTargetView( g_Targetview, color );

    return;
}


void EndScene()
{
    g_Swapchain->Present( 0, 0 );

    return;
}


void Render()
{

    // Clear the back buffer
    float Clearcolor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f }; // red,green,blue,alpha
    g_Context->ClearRenderTargetView( g_Targetview, Clearcolor );

    // Clear the depth buffer to 1.0 (max depth)
    g_Context->ClearDepthStencilView( g_pDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0 );

    // Update variables
    CONSTANTBUFFER                  Buffer;

    Buffer.World                    = XMMatrixTranspose( g_World );
    Buffer.View                     = XMMatrixTranspose( g_View );
    Buffer.Projection               = XMMatrixTranspose( g_Projection );
    Buffer.Scaling                  = XMMatrixTranspose( g_Scaling );
    g_Context->UpdateSubresource( g_ConstantBuffer, 0, NULL, &Buffer, 0, 0 );

    // Render
    g_Context->VSSetShader( g_VertexShader, NULL, 0 );
    g_Context->VSSetConstantBuffers( 0, 1, &g_ConstantBuffer );
    g_Context->PSSetShaderResources( 0, 1, &g_TextureRV );
    g_Context->PSSetShaderResources( 1, 1, &g_PaletteRV);
    g_Context->PSSetSamplers( 0, 1, &g_Sampler );
    g_Context->PSSetShader( g_PixelShader, NULL, 0 );
    g_Context->Draw( 4, 0 );

    // Present our back buffer to our front buffer
    g_Swapchain->Present( 0, 0 );
}
```

and the shaders:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// File: Tutorial04.fx
//
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Texture2D txTexture : register( t0 );
Texture2D txPalette : register( t1 );
SamplerState sampling : register( s0 );

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Constant Buffer Variables
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register( b0 )
{
    matrix Scaling;
    matrix World;
    matrix View;
    matrix Projection;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vertex Shader
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS_INPUT VS( VS_INPUT input )
{
    PS_INPUT output = (PS_INPUT)0;
    output.Pos = mul( input.Pos, Scaling);
    output.Pos = mul( output.Pos, World );
    output.Pos = mul( output.Pos, View );
    output.Pos = mul( output.Pos, Projection );
    output.Tex = input.Tex;
    output.Color = input.Color;

    return output;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Pixel Shader
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
float4 PS( PS_INPUT input ) : SV_Target
{
    float4 Index = txTexture.Sample( sampling, input.Tex );
    float w, h;
    txPalette.GetDimensions( w, h );
    return txPalette.Sample( sampling, float2( ( Index.r * 255.0 ) / w, 0 ) );
}
```

The final rendering has some garbage on the texture, but i don't know WHAT cause it.
Sampling, blending? What i'm missing?

The correct one is on the right.

[image]

The first texture use the red channel as index for the right texel on the second texture.

@Andon Coleman

This image show the texture ( the rightmost one) with +0.5 added to get the center of the texel.

[image]

Comment: You really should not be using those coordinates to sample with, especially when you use BORDER for your address mode. Your first and last palette entries are going to be replaced with a constant color. Consider `float2( ( Index.r * 255.0  + 0.5 ) / w, 0.5 )` instead. Now each of your U/V coordinates will sample your palette texture exactly at the center of a texel instead of at the border.

Comment: @Andon - Thank, you for the reply.  I have edited the question and added an image with your suggestion, but the result is almost identically.

Comment: You could also try to use `txPalette.Load(int3(Index.r, 0, 0))` (which uses integer coordinates) to avoid any sampling, filtering or mipmapping. (You might also want to change the type of your index texture to int or uint as well)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i have modified the shader with the Load instruction suggested by @melak47, and now is working.

```
Texture2D<float4> txPalette : register( t1 );

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Pixel Shader
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
float4 PS( PS_INPUT input ) : SV_Target
{
    float4 Index = txTexture.Sample( sampling, input.Tex );
    return txPalette.Load( int3( Index.r * 255.0 + 0.5, 0, 0 ) );
}
```

To get the correct color, i had to add the 0.5 offset. 
Thank you for the help.